# Hadoop MapReduce job is using only two reducers out of 16

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to Hadoop MR. I have a 4 node cluster which has 32 Map slots and 16 Reduce slots. Job is processing close to 100 GB of data using 761 Maps and 2 Reducers.

My question is why is it using 2 reducers only. Please let me if I missed any configuration related to Reducers or it is expected.

I have set below property in mapreduce configuration but still it is using 2 reducers.

Default Number of Reduce Tasks per Job

mapred.reduce.tasks=8

Log:

```
15/12/30 14:58:56 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201512301313_0002
15/12/30 14:58:56 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 33
15/12/30 14:58:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File System Counters
15/12/30 14:58:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of bytes read=11711801793
15/12/30 14:58:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of bytes written=24324166884
15/12/30 14:58:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of read operations=0
15/12/30 14:58:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of large read operations=0
15/12/30 14:58:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of write operations=0
15/12/30 14:58:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS: Number of bytes read=101855418108
15/12/30 14:58:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS: Number of bytes written=821001518
15/12/30 14:58:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS: Number of read operations=1536
15/12/30 14:58:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
15/12/30 14:58:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS: Number of write operations=2
15/12/30 14:58:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters
15/12/30 14:58:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=761
15/12/30 14:58:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched reduce tasks=2
15/12/30 14:58:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=753
15/12/30 14:58:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Rack-local map tasks=8
15/12/30 14:58:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=10467348
15/12/30 14:58:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=936182
15/12/30 14:58:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
15/12/30 14:58:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use prime number reducers. Can you provide the logs or something where it says it is using only 2 Reducers.

Comment: @younghobbit, added log in the original message.